# Fonts and some graphics disappear / lost after hibernate / sleep / resume / cycle

Tags: pantheon-terminal, graphics, suspend, fonts

Almost always after a sleep or hibernate (I'm not entirely sure which) most fonts, such as those in **Terminal** and most other programs (not Firefox) disappear. How can I fix this?

I am using the Loki version of the OS.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot about the issue?

Comment: @lemonslice, gah, I'd have to revert the kernel to test. It looks exactly like this: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/5607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Prof. Falken.*

I searched on forums high and low to solve this issue. I can not remember where I found the solution, but this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
```

The consensus seemed to be that there is a slight problem with the Intel graphics driver in the default kernel and that switching to the generic kernel works around or fixes the issue.